# Issues finding NSManagedObject during Core Data deletion for to-one relationship

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

**UPDATE**: Martin R below has provided a very clear (and succinct!) answer that *almosts* answers my question. I suppose I should rephrase:

Can you think of any reasons why fetching NSManagedObjects that are connected to another NSManagedObject wouldn't work when calling `prepareForDeletion`, given that such objects are connected one-to-one to the object being deleted?

I need to be able to call `prepareForDeletion` so that I can run some entity checking before deciding whether I should delete an object's children.

---

Are there any tricks to deleting an object's children objects in Core Data when it is a one-to-one relationship?

I have a rather complex Core Data model wherein deleting a single NSManagedObject should also delete its children NSManagedObjects via `prepareForDeletion`. Running a series of debugging NSLog statements immediately prior to deletion reveals that all relationships have been set up properly. However, when actually attempting to delete the object, it seems many (though not all) of these relationships have been lost, as attempting to fetch some (but again, not all) of these objects via NSFetchRequest returns empty arrays.

I can't seem to figure out any differences between how I fetch the objects that are found versus the objects that are not found, other than that those that are found are inverse to-many relationships while those that cannot be found are one-to-one relationships :-/

To delete the "main" object I simply call `[managedObjectContext deleteObject:mainObject];`, and within the main object's private API I have overwritten `prepareForDeletion` as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForDeletion
{
//    [super prepareForDeletion]; // commented but uncommenting doesn't change results
    [MyDataManager deleteChildOneForMainObject:self];
    [MyDataManager deleteChildrenTwoForMainObject:self];
    [MyDataManager deleteChildrenThreeForMainObject:self];
}
```

where `MyDataManager` is a custom NSObject containing only class methods. MyDataManager then searches for corresponding NSManagedObjects in the managed object context via something akin to the following:

```
- (BOOL)deleteChildOneForMainObject:(MainObject *)mainObject
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ChildOne" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];
    [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(mainObject == %@)", mainObject]];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *childOnesToDelete = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    if (childOnesToDelete.count > 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"[WARNING] More than one ChildOne for mainObject found; deleting all");
    }
    NSLog(@"[TEST] Deleting %i ChildOnes", childOnesToDelete.count);
    for (ChildOne *childOne in childOnesToDelete)
    {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:childOne];
    }
    if ([managedObjectContext save:&error]) return YES;
    else NSLog(@"[WARNING] Save error for function [deleteChildOneForMainObject:]");
    return NO;
}
```

Again, each NSManagedObject of type "MainObject" has a one-to-one relationship to "ChildOne" and one-to-many relationships with "ChildTwo" and "ChildThree". "Child One," "ChildTwo," and "ChildThree" all have to-one relationships with "MainObject."

Comment: An easier solution could be to set the "Delete Rule" of the relationship from *MainObject* to *ChildX* to "Cascade". Then deleting an object of the *MainObject* entity would automatically delete all related objects of the *ChildX* entity.

Comment: As @MartinR suggested you should play with delete rules. What type of rules do you use? Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Comment: From *ChildX* to *MainObject* set nullify. This means: if a child is deleted, do nothing on the parent.

Comment: Does "Cascade" go 1-level deep? How would I prevent other objects from being deleted if they are also in the hierarchy? E.g., ChildTwo is also tied one-to-one to object HouseOne but I don't want HouseOne to delete when ChildTwo is deleted via MainObject.

Comment: @KenHaggerty: That would depend on the delete rule from ChildTwo to HouseOne, so you can control that separately.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR Is there any way to set this programmatically? I really hate storyboard / xcdatamodelId and find that many of my "bugs" are just checkboxes I forgot to uncheck in storyboard.

Comment: Do you create the relationships programmatically??? Then set e.g.  `[childOneRelation setDeleteRule:NSCascadeDeleteRule]`.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah via @dynamic within each NSManagedObject's file. Where would `[entriesRelation setDeleteRule:NSCascadeDeleteRule] go? I don't believe you can use setters and getters in NSManagedObjects when connecting to other NSManagedObjects(?).

Comment: @KenHaggerty: Sorry, but I don't understand you anymore. If you define the entity in the Xcode model editor, then just set the "Delete Rule" to "Cascade" in the Core Data Model inspector. If you define the `NSRelationshipDescription` programmatically, then add `setDeleteRule: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally got IRC to work for me! and a helpful person on the #iphonedev channel provided these insights:

• (Like Martin R said) I should put up with the visual interface for constructing my Core Data model and use the provided "Delete Rule" dropdown menus to create my deletion logic. (In the "Utilities" right-side pane, third tab that looks like a wedge of cheese.) "Cascade" and "Nullify" are the most useful values.

• "Delete Rules" are one-way and unique to each relationship, so you have a fair degree of control.

• Instead of fetching an NSManagedObject that has a one-to-one relationship with a provided NSManagedObject, just use the property. Using a fetch as a "safeguarding" mechanism is stupid and unnecessary since this relation is one-to-one by definition. So if I have `Ying` and `Yang` objects, I should just perform `[managedObjectContext deleteObject:ying.yang]` or `[managedObjectContext deleteObject:yang.ying]`.

Ultimately `prepareForDeletion` was only relevant with regards to cascading deletion as per Martin R's answer.

Comment: Is there a way to "accept" two answers? Martin R's answer was like 66% of the solution.

Comment: No, unfortunately not :-) According to the FAQ one should accept the answer that is "the most helpful". It is perfectly OK if you accept your own answer (I would have no problem with that).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting "dependent" objects can be automatically handled by Core Data if you set the "Delete Rule" for the relationships properly. In this case, you can set

- delete rule for relationship from *MainObject* to *ChildX* to "Cascade",
- delete rule for inverse relationship from *ChildX* to *MainObject* to "Nullify".

That means

- If a *MainObject* is deleted, the related *ChildX* object is also deleted.
- If a *ChildX* object is deleted, the relationship value from the related *MainObject* is set to NULL.

Comment: AH okay. I did not realize that delete rules were one-directional.